# DataContext update and rollback

Tags: c#, datacontext, rollback, submitchanges

I'm having a problem with my DataContext. In the following code snippet, I first delete existing objects in my datacontext, and later in same code, adding new again. The problem is, since I'm using .DeleteOnSubmit() its still containing 2 entities in my Datacontext, tho its stored correctly in my Database.

Here the code:

```
public void ConnectedApartment(Apartment newApartment, Apartment existing)
{
    ConApart ConApartTemp = new ConApart();
    ConApartTemp.Apartment1 = newApartment;
    ConApartTemp.Apartment = existing;
    DatabaseConnection.ConAparts.InsertOnSubmit(ConApartTemp);
}

public void opdaterConApart(ArrayList connected, Apartment Apartmenten)
{
    foreach (ConApart sam in Apartmenten.ConAparts)
    {
      DatabaseConnection.ConAparts.DeleteOnSubmit(sam);
    }
    foreach (ConApart sam2 in Apartmenten.ConAparts1)
    {
      DatabaseConnection.ConAparts.DeleteOnSubmit(sam2);
    }

    foreach (Apartment apa in connected)
    {
      ConnectedApartment(apa, Apartmenten);
    }
    DatabaseConnection.SubmitChanges();
}
```

If I doesn't SubmitChanges() of the delete before

```
    foreach (Apartment apa in connected)
    {
      ConnectedApartment(apa, Apartmenten);
    }
```

Then my Datacontext will contain 2 entities, and my gui will show duplicates for each time its changing.

If I use following:

```
public void ConnectedApartment(Apartment newApartment, Apartment existing)
{
    ConApart ConApartTemp = new ConApart();
    ConApartTemp.Apartment1 = newApartment;
    ConApartTemp.Apartment = existing;
    DatabaseConnection.ConAparts.InsertOnSubmit(ConApartTemp);
}

public void opdaterConApart(ArrayList connected, Apartment Apartmenten)
{
    foreach (ConApart sam in Apartmenten.ConAparts)
    {
      DatabaseConnection.ConAparts.DeleteOnSubmit(sam);
    }
    foreach (ConApart sam2 in Apartmenten.ConAparts1)
    {
      DatabaseConnection.ConAparts.DeleteOnSubmit(sam2);
    }

    DatabaseConnection.SubmitChanges();

    foreach (Apartment apa in connected)
    {
      ConnectedApartment(apa, Apartmenten);
    }
    DatabaseConnection.SubmitChanges();
}
```

then it works, but that solution is weak for Rollback function, since it going to:
 1. Delete existing objects
 2. submitChanges
 3. Add new objects
 4. submitChanges

But if something fails between point 2 and 3, the objects that are deleted is lost.
Any suggestions? How can I maintain my context, so it doesn't hang with double entities, and still handle Rollback functionality if something goes wrong???

Comment: The correct rollback process for a date-context is: *throw it away* (dispose it if necessary). A data-context is intended to be a short-lived unit-of-work, not a long-lived representation of your entire database.

Comment: That makes sense to the rollback. But I still have the problem, that I need commit the delete of the object, before adding, to avoid getting duplicates hanging in my DataContext.